# Parse OS X issue

Tags: macos, swift, parse-platform

I'm creating an OS X app using Parse. I correctly set the `appId` in my `AppDelegate`, however when running it, the console shows:

> Failed to set (contentViewController) user defined inspected property on (NSWindow): You have to call setApplicationId:clientKey: on Parse to configure Parse.

and the content of my view controller can not be loaded.
If I comment the code in the `-viewDidLoad:` of the view controller, everything works well...
Is the `-viewDidLoad:` called before `-applicationDidFinishLaunching:options:"`?

```
func applicationDidFinishLaunching(aNotification: NSNotification) {
    Parse.enableLocalDatastore()        
    Parse.setApplicationId("LAckhYSKt33A7hoepKgk3x1K8af1EYhiK1YHY7cH", clientKey:"Pr1PE5ROC9AMoPquzSfA9FltIzIk6QLKdNXXh5fx")
    println("fait")
    //PFUser.enableAutomaticUser()

    let defaultACL: PFACL = PFACL()
    defaultACL.setPublicReadAccess(true)
    PFACL.setDefaultACL(defaultACL, withAccessForCurrentUser: true)
}
```

Any reason for such a strange behavior??

Comment: Add breakpoints and check.

Comment: Add your, `AppDelegate`'s `didFinishLaunching` function please.

Comment: can you post it in the original question so we can actually read the function